# Install routinely failing after database authentication

Tags: 7, installation

I am having the worst time installing drupal 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 on an amazon aws ec2 instance and I don't know why. I've never had this much trouble before. No matter how closely to a T I follow these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-on-a-virtual-server-running-ubuntu-12-04 (i really can't imagine 12.04 being that different from 14.04, i'm not doing anything fancy) it always results in the following failure:

So I get the LAMP stack installed and set up and verify it's working correctly. And I create the database and the database user and verify that that's all working. And I download and move all the files to `/var/www/html` and start the install. Everything goes fine until I hit the database connection stage. I put in the credentials, it thinks, then the database connection page refreshes and the fields are empty. At this point I go and I check the database and there are 31 tables created by Drupal, so it is connecting and modifying the database.

So what else can I do but restart the install, and when I do it jumps to the site information page, so I add that information, save it and I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in /var/www/html/includes/entity.inc on line 321` (which would otherwise be a WSOD, but at least I have development debug turned on)

If I just go to the site now, the default drupal page comes up but only with:
`Page not found
The requested page "/" could not be found.`

It's really throwing me here, I've Googled the error and the results are just so all over the place and I have no idea why I can't even get this thing installed before something goes wrong. This is not my first time installing a drupal site, have done it many times before on ubuntu servers from amazon aws and non-virtual servers.

Answer (score 1):

Guess there are a ton of answers here for the exact same problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1171756.

Don't really want to duplicate them.

**update:** In my case I needed to `chown -R www-data` the directory my drupal files were in, apparently ownership was somehow changed from the apache server, had to change it back. there you have it.